# How to access variable value outside subscribe call back?

Tags: typescript

What is the way to access zvol_name_array after the result of subscribe callback. I am seeing in my Google Dev Tools that, this.zvol_name_array is undefined and I know there is some relevant data in `vol_list['vol_name']`.

```
public zvol_name_array: Array<String> = [];
public zvol_object: Array<object> = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    function find_nested_zvol(zvol: any): String {...snip...}
    this.rest.get(this.volume_resource_name , {}).subscribe((res) => {
      for(let zvol_list of res.data) {
        this.zvol_name_array.push(zvol_list['vol_name']);
      }
    });
```

Comment: zvol_list returned value (while push) should be a string. Is it string now? But I don't see any problem! It should work as expected!

Comment: How is the function `find_nested_zvol` used? Please post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
public zvol_name_array: Array<String> = [];
public zvol_object: Array<object> = [];

ngOnInit() {
    function find_nested_zvol(zvol: any): String {...snip...}

    let parentThis = this;
    this.rest.get(this.volume_resource_name , {}).subscribe((res) => {
        for(let zvol_list of res.data) {
            parentThis.zvol_name_array.push(zvol_list['vol_name']);
        }
    });
}
```

This is because the parent scope this is overwritten by this of subscribe scope